# equivalent to `pg_rules` in `information_schema`

Tags: postgresql, rules

I know, `information_schema` is SQL standard, and `RULES` are Postgres SQL extensions.

Still, is there a way to list all availible rules using `information_schema`?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Comment: @Tomalak, I'm writing the tag in the title, when the question's type might be misleading. For instance "Why isn't `toString` called `asString`", it can be in many languages. I suspect that the question might not be as clear without Postgres mentioned in the title.

Comment: Stack Overflow already has the tags feature. That's where tags go to indicate the topic of a question. Repeating them in the title is redundant and rather subverts the entire purpose of having the consistent, indexable tags feature.

Comment: @Tomalak, the tags are not very visible, especially when you're having more than one tag. And if you need to search the tag only to understand what the question means (Java's `toString`, or C#'s?) it's not good. What if someone copy-pastes the question? They'll usually won't bother to copy the tags. I argue that the question must be coherent even without seeing the tags. In my view the tags are meant to ease indexing, not to add information to the question.

Comment: Regardless, they are both, and writing tags in titles is both redundant and discouraged. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, according to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/information-schema.html):

> The information schema views do not,
>   however, contain information about
>   PostgreSQL-specific features; to
>   inquire about those you need to query
>   the system catalogs or other
>   PostgreSQL-specific views.

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
SELECT
  n.nspname                   AS view_schema,
  c.relname                   AS view_name,
  r.rulename                  AS rule_name,
  pg_get_ruledef(r.oid, true) AS compiled_definition,
  d.description               AS full_description,
  CASE ev_type::integer
      WHEN 2 THEN 'update'
      WHEN 3 THEN 'insert'
      WHEN 4 THEN 'delete'
  END AS rule_event

FROM
  pg_rewrite AS r
  LEFT JOIN pg_class AS c ON c.oid = r.ev_class
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace AS n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
  LEFT JOIN pg_description AS d ON r.oid = d.objoid
WHERE TRUE
AND n.nspname != 'pg_catalog'
AND r.rulename <> '_RETURN' AND relkind = 'v'
ORDER BY r.rulename
```